# How to send as JS value to Bean using ActionListener?

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

Is there a way to send some JS value to my bean, using the ActionListener property of a p:commandButton?

Example:

```
<p:inputText id="txtColaborador1"></p:inputText>
<p:commandButton ajax="true" actionListener="#{demandaController.validarLogin(document.getElementById('form\:j_idt100\:txtColaborador1').value)}""></p:commandButton>
```

And in my Bean:

```
....
public class DemandaController 
     public void validarLogin(String text1) {
         //....
     }
}
```

Also, would be better using widgetVar.

I'm already providing another solution for this case, cause i can recover that text value in my bean....but still, is there way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using [Primefaces Remote Command](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/remoteCommand.jsf)

*remoteCommand*

```
<p:remoteCommand name="validarLoginCommand" 
             actionListener="#{demandaController.validarLogin()}"/>
```

*Button*

```
 <p:inputText id="txtColaborador1" widgetVar="txtColaboradorVar"></p:inputText>
 <p:commandButton onclick="handleLogin()"></p:commandButton>
```

*JS*

```
function handleLogin() {
   myJSValue = txtColaboradorVar.jq.val();
   validarLoginCommand([{name: 'myJSValue', value: myJSValue}]);
}
```

*Managed Bean*

```
public void validarLogin() {
     FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
     Map map = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
     myJSValue = (String) map.get("myJSValue");
 }
```

Hope this Helps.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you :)